# angular.js:14525 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting this error in browser console.Though my code is working but with this error.

```
angular.js:14525 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
    at angular.js:38
    at n (angular.js:18524)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:18259)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:26999)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
    at m.$scope.validateUploadedDocuments (controller.js:1081)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:15358), <anonymous>:4:195)
    at e (angular.js:26994)
    at m.$eval (angular.js:18161) undefined
```

This is my code .. I tried using timeout as per other posts solution , but it doesn't work. Can anyone suggest some other solution.I am getting error in function validateUploadedDocuments when getUploadedDocument service is called.

```
$scope.validateUploadedDocuments=function(){

        var obj={};

        obj.combiId =  $scope.applicationParams.combiId;
        var indm;
        var ob = localStorageService.get("ageExtraPremiumObj");
        if(!ob) ob = {};

        service.getUploadedDocument(obj).then(function(res) {


                for(var j=0;j<res.data.length;j++){
                    if(res.data[j].documentType=="AadhaarCard" || res.data[j].documentType=="Passport"){
                        if(res.data[j].proofType=="Age Proof"){
                            removeMandetory();
                        }
                        else if(res.data[j].proofType=="Address Proof"){
                           removeMandetory();   
                        }else if(res.data[j].proofType=="ID Proof"){
                            removeMandetory();
                        }
                    }

                 for(var i=0;i<$scope.mandetoryDocuments.length;i++){   

                    if(res.data[j].proofType==$scope.mandetoryDocuments[i].proofType){
                        $scope.mandetoryDocuments[i].uploaded=true;
                    }

                 }
                }


        });         
    };
```

Comment: This might be due to digest cycle of angularJS, While first cycle is in running phase, timeout function is triggering changes due to that second cycle is started before completion of first.

Comment: @chetan Hirapara.. Thanks for Info.. But how to overcome same as I have already tried timeout on service calling .

Comment: Can we please see the contents of `service.getUploadedDocument`?

Comment: Its just a normal webService for getting uploadedDocuments which is getting response from server side, so error is not related to it.

Comment: do you have any calls $scope.$apply, $scope.$digest, $rootScope.$apply, $rootScope.$digest in your code?

Comment: Yes, $scope.apply is used in other method on same page.

Comment: @ShilpiJaiswal This $scope.apply is the issue. Have you tried by increase timrout milli seconds?